# OnePress wp theme: About Team section

Tags: php, wordpress

Please i am using OnePress wp theme (free version) and the maximum team members is 4 and i would like to have 8 members in team section. I meant 4 one the first row and 4 on the second row.

Please could you help?
Thanks

Below is the section-team.php

```html
<?php
$onepress_team_id       = get_theme_mod( 'onepress_team_id', esc_html__('team', 'onepress') );
$onepress_team_disable  = get_theme_mod( 'onepress_team_disable' ) ==  1 ? true : false;
$onepress_team_title    = get_theme_mod( 'onepress_team_title', esc_html__('Our Team', 'onepress' ));
$onepress_team_subtitle = get_theme_mod( 'onepress_team_subtitle', esc_html__('Section subtitle', 'onepress' ));
$layout = intval( get_theme_mod( 'onepress_team_layout', 3 ) );
if ( $layout <= 0 ){
    $layout = 3;
}
$user_ids = onepress_get_section_team_data();
if ( onepress_is_selective_refresh() ) {
    $onepress_team_disable = false;
}
if ( ! empty( $user_ids ) ) {
    $desc = get_theme_mod( 'onepress_team_desc' );
    ?>
  <?php if ( ! $onepress_team_disable ) : ?>
  <?php if ( ! onepress_is_selective_refresh() ){ ?>
  <section id="<?php if ($onepress_team_id != '') echo $onepress_team_id; ?>" <?php do_action( 'onepress_section_atts', 'team'); ?>
    class="
    <?php echo esc_attr(apply_filters('onepress_section_class', 'section-team section-padding section-meta onepage-section', 'team')); ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <?php do_action('onepress_section_before_inner', 'team'); ?>
    <div class="container">
      <?php if ( $onepress_team_title || $onepress_team_subtitle || $desc ){ ?>
      <div class="section-title-area">
        <?php if ($onepress_team_subtitle != '') echo '<h5 class="section-subtitle">' . esc_html($onepress_team_subtitle) . '</h5>'; ?>
        <?php if ($onepress_team_title != '') echo '<h2 class="section-title">' . esc_html($onepress_team_title) . '</h2>'; ?>
        <?php if ( $desc ) {
                        echo '<div class="section-desc">' . apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_kses_post( $desc ) ) . '</div>';
                    } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="team-members row team-layout-<?php echo intval( 12 / $layout  ); ?>">
        <?php
                    if ( ! empty( $user_ids ) ) {
                        $n = 0;

                        foreach ( $user_ids as $member ) {
                            $member = wp_parse_args( $member, array(
                                'user_id'  =>array(),
                            ));

                            $link = isset( $member['link'] ) ?  $member['link'] : '';
                            $user_id = wp_parse_args( $member['user_id'],array(
                                'id' => '',
                             ) );

                            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $user_id['id'], 'onepress-small' );
                            $image_alt = get_post_meta( $user_id['id'], '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);

                            if ( $image_attributes ) {
                                $image = $image_attributes[0];
                                $data = get_post( $user_id['id'] );
                                $n ++ ;
                                ?>
          <div class="team-member wow slideInUp">
            <div class="member-thumb">
              <?php if ( $link ) { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>">
                <?php } ?>
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_alt; ?>">
                <?php if ( $link ) { ?>
              </a>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php do_action( 'onepress_section_team_member_media', $member ); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="member-info">
              <h5 class="member-name">
                <?php if ( $link ) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>">
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php echo esc_html( $data->post_title ); ?>
                  <?php if ( $link ) { ?>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>
              </h5>
              <span class="member-position"><?php echo esc_html( $data->post_content ); ?></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php
                            }

                        } // end foreach
                    }

                    ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php do_action('onepress_section_after_inner', 'team'); ?>
    <?php if ( ! onepress_is_selective_refresh() ){ ?>
  </section>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit customizer.php, find the section Team and edit the line: max_item'      => 4, // Maximum item can add

```
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new Onepress_Customize_Repeatable_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'onepress_team_members',
            array(
                'label'     => esc_html__('Team members', 'onepress'),
                'description'   => '',
                'section'       => 'onepress_team_content',
                //'live_title_id' => 'user_id', // apply for unput text and textarea only
                'title_format'  => esc_html__( '[live_title]', 'onepress'), // [live_title]
                'max_item'      => 4, // Maximum item can add
                'limited_msg'   => wp_kses_post( 'Upgrade to <a target="_blank" href="https://www.famethemes.com/plugins/onepress-plus/?utm_source=theme_customizer&utm_medium=text_link&utm_campaign=onepress_customizer#get-started">OnePress Plus</a> to be able to add more items and unlock other premium features!', 'onepress' ),
```